# Calculating the length of a Japanese multibyte string with half-width kana in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

So I have a UTF-8 encoded string which can contain full-width kanji, full-width kana, half-width kana, romaji, numbers or kawaii japanese symbols like ★ or  ♥.

If I want the length I use `mb_strlen()` and it counts each of these as 1 in length. Which is fine for most purposes.

But, I've been asked (by a Japanese client) to only count half-width kana as 0.5 (for the purpose of maxlength of a text field) because apparently thats how Japanese websites do it. I do this using `mb_strwidth()` which counts full-width as 2, and half-width as 1, then i just divide by 2.

However this method also counts romaji characters as 1 so something like `Chocｱｲｽ` would count as 7 .. then i'd divide by 2 to account for kanji and I'd get 3.5. but I actually want 5.5 (4 for the Romaji + 1.5 for the 3 half-width kana).

// EDIT:
some more info: any character (even non-kana) which has both a full and a half should be 1 for the full-width and 0.5 for the half-width. for example, characters like `￥、３＠（` should all be 1, but characters like `¥,3@(` should all be 0.5

// EXTRA EDIT: symbols like ☆ and ♥ should be 1, but the mb_strwidth/2 method return them as 0.5

Is there a standard way that Japanese systems count string length?
Or does everyone just loop thru their strings and count the characters which don't match the standard width rules?

Comment: My spontaneous idea would be to use `mb_strlen` as usual and subtract the number of occurrences of characters between the Unicode code points FF61 and FF9F. I might work this out into a full answer later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found no answer for this.

I fixed it by literally iterating thru and checking each character and manually applying the counting rules that my client asked for.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>One way is to convert the half-width katakana to full-width and subtract the difference in width from the original length:</strike>

```
$raw = 'Chocｱｲｽ';
$full = mb_convert_kana($raw, 'K');
$len = mb_strlen($raw) - (mb_strwidth($full) - mb_strwidth($raw))/2;
assert($len === 5.5);
```

**However**, are you *sure* that you should be considering basic latin characters as full-width? There do exist full-width varieties of basic latin characters too---that is, should `Choc` be considered the same as `Ｃｈｏｃ`?

Usually, characters like "A" and "ｱ" would have a width of 1, but "Ａ" and "ア" would have a width of 2 (which is what `mb_strwidth` does). I'd be cautious about having to hack around that.

---

**Given your edit**, `mb_strwidth` (or `mb_strwidth/2`) does exactly what you want.

Comment: i really should clarify more; but symbols (♥☆ etc) should be 1, and they return 0.5 in the mb_strwidth/2 method. its all very confusing, but my question is really searching for what "standard rules" are for this type of thing? or is my client just making it up as he goes along? (he is a very successful and experienced businessman).

Comment: Those symbols (♥☆) aren't full-width though. As for standard rules, [Unicode TR11](http://unicode.org/reports/tr11/) documents how characters are classified as either full- or half-width.

Comment: Hi, I am aware that they are no full-width according to my code, but I have been asked to count them as 1 length. My client reassured me his rules were standard, and showed me on a popular website (http://www.gnavi.co.jp/) with a bunch of examples which matched his rules. I was just kinda hoping there was a safer way than me hand coding the rules from his explanation. Maybe i need to find stackoverflow in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Perl’s [Unicode::GCString](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aGCString) module: it give the correct columns for all Unicode, including the East Asian stuff.

It is an underlying component of [Unicode::LineBreak](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aLineBreak), which I have found absolutely indispensable for doing proper text segmentation of Asian scripts.

As you might well imagine, both are *Made in Japan™.*
 :)